# How do I get the geo location for a browser not server website is on

Tags: php, api-design, weather

OK, I have this script and it works but:

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
// access_token received from /oauth2/token call
// Assign it the properties of id (optional - id of target HTML element, from URL)
// and 'message' - the feedback message we want the user to see.
if (isset($_GET['wxurl'])) {
    $wxURL = $_GET['wxurl'];
}

if ($wxURL === "autoip") {
    //Get the IP of the location
    $uri = curl_init("http://api.wunderground.com/api/<APIKEY>/geolookup/q/autoip.json");
} else if ($wxURL === "wxcity") {
    if (isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['state'])) {
        $wxCity = $_GET['city'];
        $wxState = $_GET['state'];
    }
    //Get the locations weather data
    $uri = curl_init("http://api.wunderground.com/api/<APIKEY>/conditions/q/" . $wxState . "/" . $wxCity . ".json");
} else if ($wxURL === "freeJSON") {
    //This gets the ACTUAL USERS location NOT that of the server **<--- WELL it's SUPPOSED to get the LOCATION of the user NOT the server**
    $uri = curl_init("http://freegeoip.net/json/");
}

$ch = $uri; // URL of the call
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer $access_token"));
// execute the api call
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

PS - I blocked my API key with weather underground because i'll get enormous hits. It's FREE so fill in your own key.

My problem: When I poll use my LOCALHOST, I get weather for my own CITY, but, when use the site on the server, it PULLS the data from the SERVER's LOCATION... So if I'm here on the west coast, the server is in Temple, PA.

How can I get the locale data for a customer when the code pulls the server data???

UPDATE: I found this: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html but what I get is: UNABLE TO GET YOUR LOCATION. That's because I have GEO LOC turned off in my browser but when I use the http://freegeoip.net/json this is what I get:

```
{
    ip: "11.22.333.444",
    country_code: "US",
    country_name: "United States",
    region_code: "WA",
    region_name: "Washington",
    city: "MT Vernon",
    zip_code: "98273",
    time_zone: "America/Los_Angeles",
    latitude: 47.5614,
    longitude: -123.7705,
    metro_code: 985
}
```

So, Geolocation.js baffles me...

Thoughts?